# How to calculate flux density in a toroidal CT that has an electrical line pass through the center?

Tags: current, transformer, flux, core

I have seen the Biot-Savart equation but I don't know how to apply it. Also does the conductor length need to be considered finite and equal to the core length or will the calculation be for infinite length conductor?

Comment: enhance your question by adding more details about your question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to avoid the Biot-Savart rule and instead determine the magnetic field strength, H. This can then be converted to flux density (B) by multiplying H by \$\mu_0\mu_r\$.

\$\mu_0 \times\mu_r\$ is the magnetic permeability of your toroid material.

H is the ampere-turns per meter applied where metres are the mean length of the magnetic field and for a toroid that is approximately the length round the toroid. Amps is amps and turns is turns. For a CT this converts to just amps because you have a single turn.